# Why is "server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client" not solved by insecure-registries?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am running a docker registry locally.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name local-registry registry:2
```

...and I have dutifully added its host and port to the daemon.json (~/.docker/daemon.json on my mac)...

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : [ "192.168.4.26:5000" ],
  "debug" : true,
  "experimental" : false,
  "builder" : { 
    "gc" : { 
      "defaultKeepStorage" : "20GB",
      "enabled" : true
    }   
  }
}
```

AND I restarted everything, the whole machine just to be sure.  It shows up in my **docker info**.

```
 Insecure Registries:
  192.168.4.26:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
```

And yet!  When I go to deploy my service...

```
kubectl delete pod test
kubectl run test --image 192.168.4.26:5000/split-server:latest
kubectl describe pod test
```

I end up with the dread **server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client**

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  17m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/test to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    16m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet            Pulling image "192.168.4.26:5000/split-server:latest"
  Warning  Failed     16m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "192.168.4.26:5000/split-server:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://192.168.4.26:5000/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
  Warning  Failed     16m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     15m (x6 over 17m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    2m32s (x66 over 17m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "192.168.4.26:5000/split-server:latest"
```

Why am I still getting this error?  I am running on OSX, minikube (which is up-to-date)...

What else can cause this problem?

Comment: because doing anything to _your mac_ doesn't change the linux virtual machine upon which `minikube` (and thus `kubelet`) is running

Comment: I tried setting the insecure registry with minkube start:  minikube start --insecure-registry="192.168.4.26".   But no luck.  I remembered to minikube delete before starting... still no luck